Interact with shadow root vba selenium
I have spent several hours in this topic and I could partially solve the problem of interacting with html that has shadow-root. here is my code but as the last part doesn't work as expected and throws an error `Object Required
Private bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub Test()
    Dim sUserFullPath As String, sLoginFullPath As String, oUserElement As Object, oLoginElement As Object
    Dim ShadowHost As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim ShadowRoot As Object
    Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    With bot
        .Get "https://onlinebanking.ebank.com.eg/?bank_id=01"
        .Window.Maximize
        .Wait 2000
        Rem User
        sUserFullPath = "/html/body/div/iron-pages/div[1]/ev-login//div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/oe-input//paper-input-container/iron-input/input"
        Set oUserElement = FindElementByFullXPath(bot, sUserFullPath)
        oUserElement.SendKeys "yyyyyy"
        .Wait 1000
        Rem Login
        sLoginFullPath = "/html/body/div/iron-pages/div[1]/ev-login//div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/paper-button/oe-i18n-msg"
        Set oLoginElement = FindElementByFullXPath(bot, sLoginFullPath)
        oLoginElement.Click
        
        Rem This part doesn't work as the previous
        Dim sPassFullPath As String
        sPassFullPath = "/html/body/div/iron-pages/div[1]/ev-login//div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/oe-input//paper-input-container/iron-input/input"
        Dim oPassElement As Object
        Set oPassElement = FindElementByFullXPath(bot, sPassFullPath)
        oPassElement.SendKeys "kkkkkk"
    End With
End Sub

Function FindElementByFullXPath(ByVal bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver, ByVal sFullXPath As String) As Object
    Dim x
    x = SplitXPathByShadowRoots(sFullXPath)
    Set FindElementByFullXPath = FindElementAcrossShadows(bot, x)
End Function

Function SplitXPathByShadowRoots(ByVal sFullXPath As String)
    Dim x, i As Long
    x = Split(sFullXPath, "//")
    ReDim result(UBound(x))
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        If i = 0 Then result(i) = "/" & x(i) Else result(i) = x(i)
    Next i
    SplitXPathByShadowRoots = result
End Function

Function FindElementAcrossShadows(ByVal bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver, ByVal x) As Object
    Dim oElement As Object, i As Long
    Set oElement = bot.FindElementByXPath(x(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(x)
        Set oElement = bot.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", oElement)
        Set oElement = bot.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].querySelector('" & CSS_Selector(x(i)) & "')", oElement)
        If oElement Is Nothing Then Debug.Print "Element Not Found": Exit Function
    Next i
    Set FindElementAcrossShadows = oElement
End Function

Function CSS_Selector(ByVal myXPath As String) As String
    CSS_Selector = Replace(myXPath, "/", " > ")
    CSS_Selector = Replace(sCSS, "[", ":nth-child(")
    CSS_Selector = Replace(sCSS, "]", ")")
End Function


And which line throws this error?

you can try the code. the part of sending the password doesn't work as the previous parts.
